# Need help to setup RichEdit

Tags: c++, winapi, rtf

I'm trying to set the following text in RichEdit (v2.0 I guess, as I use "Riched20.dll" library):

> {\rtf1Привет!\par{ \i This } is super {\b text}.\par}

The first problem is wrong symbols instead of non-latin text `Привет`, the second problem is bold text section `{\\b text}`, which is rendered as non bold. Here is the screenshot:

[image: RTF example]

Visual Studio set up to "Use Unicode Character Set" (the app I'm working on is already setuped this way, and I'm still quiet bad in how Win encodings work). I use ordinar (e.g. not wide char) std::string, as wide char classes don't work for my code - that was my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69740993/wrong-handle-while-setting-text-to-richedit-control).

Here is the code snippet:

```
    DWORD CALLBACK EditStreamInCallback(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG* pcb)
    {
        std::stringstream* rtf = (std::stringstream*)dwCookie;
        *pcb                   = rtf->readsome((char*)pbBuff, cb);
        return 0;
    }

    // ...
    auto hwndEdit = CreateRichEdit(hWnd, 100, 100, 300, 300, hInstance);
    std::stringstream rtf("{\\rtf1Привет!\\par{ \\i This } is super {\\b text}.\\par}");

    EDITSTREAM es  = { 0 };
    es.dwCookie    = (DWORD_PTR)&rtf;
    es.pfnCallback = &EditStreamInCallback;

    SendMessage(hwndEdit, EM_STREAMIN, SF_RTF, (LPARAM)&es);
```

**Update:** The end goal is: get some RTF-string (which may consists of unicode(?) text, links, etc.) from JSON like:

```
{
    "text": "{\\rtf1Привет!\\par{ \\i This } is super {\\b text}.\\par}"
}
```

, show it, handle clicks at hyperlinks, and almost certainly to modify specific symbols (the specific symbol is custom symbol that replaces original symbol in our own modified .ttf font). I didn't read the RTF documentation yet and used given string just to check out how RichEdit contol and corresponding winapi work.

The final RTF-text would be formed in RTF-editor, I suppose. Almost certainly, the WordPad.

Comment: The RTF format is not exactly right, it needs the right font for Unicode. Do you just want an initialization text for your RTF control? Is this going to be edited/saved, and does it have to be compatible with word pad? ... Also I updated the previous answer.

Comment: RTF is a strictly ASCII format, you can't store *unencoded* Unicode characters in it. You need to use appropriate RTF escape codes for handling Unicode characters (`\ansicpg`, `\u`, `\uc`, etc).  See [Unicode RTF](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading9).

Comment: @Jackdaw That only affects whether the RichEdit can handle Unicode text in general. It doesn't affect how Unicode is handled in the actual RTF itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your text according the RTF format specification:

```cpp
std::string rtf("{\\rtf1\\deff1{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\\f1\\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\\lang1033{\\f1{\\ltrch\\u1055?\\u1088?\\u1080?\\u1074?\\u1077?\\u1090?!}\\li0\\ri0\\sa0\\sb0\\fi0\\ql\\par}{\\f1{\\i\\ltrch This }{\\ltrch is super }{\\b\\ltrch text}{\\ltrch .}\\li0\\ri0\\sa0\\sb0\\fi0\\ql\\par}}}");

std::stringstream ss(rtf);
EDITSTREAM es = { 0 };
es.dwCookie = (DWORD_PTR)&ss;
es.pfnCallback = &EditStreamInCallback;
SendMessage(richedit, EM_STREAMIN, SF_RTF, (LPARAM)&es);
```

This `rtf` string produces the following text:

[image]

List of main control words used in the `rtf`string above (according the Rich Text Format (RTF) Version 1.5 Specification):

- **\rtf1**
  The RTF document Specification version is 1.
- **\deffN**
  The \deff control word specified the default font number.
- **\fonttbl**
  The \fonttbl control word introduces the font table group.
- **\lang1033**
  Applies a language to a character. N is a number corresponding to a language.

In the project settings you can define `Character Set` as `Use Unicode character`, `Use Multi-Byte Character` or `Not Set`, does not matter for this case.